# How can I restrict my app for iPhone 7 Plus only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is there anyway I can put a check so my app does not appear on App Store if the user is not using iPhone 7 Plus or in other words device with dual cameras?

Such check exists for iPhone and iPad, or arm64 only but I do not think so Apple has provided us with any such restriction that this device will be available for iPhone 7 Plus devices or devices with dual camera only.

UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities do exist but there is no key for dual camera/7Plus.

So I am looking for something like TouchID or OpenGL check which can be alternative.

Now this question specifically targeted to dual camera check which arose after iPhone 7 Plus.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Can you please answer the combination so it can help people in future as well.

Answer (score -1):

UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support the listed capabilities. Refer [apple document link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)

Comment: Yea but there is NO explicit UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities for Dual Camera. So I am looking for like TouchID or some other capability.